# Execute PS script through Jenkins: to create new file with date-stamp and copy a .txt file form remote server to the local machine

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins, powershell-3.0, jenkins-cli

```
cd D:\BackupDB  
$name = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")  
$newfolder= New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "db_$name"  
cd $newfolder  
Copy-Item -Path \\remoteserverIP\f$\backup\*.txt -destination $newfolder
```

it executes till `cd $newfolder`, and then job succeeds. Looks like the Copy-Item command is skipped. What might be going wrong?

when executing the same script on a .PS1 file, it executes successfully with all expected result. for eg: if i create a script.ps1 file with the above scripts, and run it directly without Jenkins, it works.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Additionally, please update your question to describe how, specifically, the code is being invoked from Jenkins.

Comment: Jenkins job succeeds but skips the the last command:

 :Copy-Item -Path \192.200.200.200\f$\backup*.txt -destination $newfolder

Comment: 192.200.200.200 is an ip address which is routable over the internet. Are you sure the ip is correct? Having SMB open over the internet is quite risky

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be that you "cd" into $newfolder then try to copy the files to $newfolder which in the current directory doesn't exist. I would expect an error at this point unless  you force it to create a new folder which i don't think it's what you want. If you remove the "cd $newfolder" line I'd expect this to work:

```
cd D:\BackupDB  
$name = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")  
$newfolder= New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name "db_$name"  
Copy-Item -Path \\remoteserverIP\f$\backup\*.txt -destination $newfolder
```

Comment: No improvement , it only created the folder with the time stamp, but failed to copy the .txt file into the folder. I assume , since i am trying to copy it from a remote server, there needs to be something that i am missing

Comment: @elipen You're not seeing any errors once you get to that line? Does the remote server require authentication?